# Updating ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework) to ASP.NET Core (.NET Core)

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Despite updating all incompatible .NET Core library do we need to change something to the base application?

Can we upgrade straight away or we need to copy all to a new application?

Comment: This should require no more than changing the `<TargetFramework>` in the .csproj. Have you tried that?

Comment: We are in currently in the process to choose which target framework to use. We have actually one dependency which cannot use .net CORE but will eventually. This is why I asked because we will probably switch in a near future.

Comment: Did you actually try the dependency on .NET Core? 2.0 implements .NET Standard 2.0, which has near parity with the full framework in API footprint. Most .NET Framework libraries will run on .NET Standard 2.0, unless they use a lot of Windows-specific APIs. You'll get a warning when you reference a .NET Framework library, but just to let you know that you need to test it, before assuming it works completely. Once you confirm it works, the warning can be suppressed. It's at least worth a shot if you haven't tried already, and then you can move ahead now, instead of waiting.

Comment: Also, there's a Windows compatibility NuGet you can install to shim in even more support. It's not a long term solution, but might get you over the hump until the library is updated.

Comment: It need the system.drawing one which it not available now.

Comment: That's covered in the compatibility NuGet (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/11/16/announcing-the-windows-compatibility-pack-for-net-core/). Install that and you should be able to target Core. Just put it on your timeline to switch out System.Drawing with something like ImageSharp at some point.